# WPF ListView that supports inline edit?

Tags: wpf, listview

Is there a open source WPF control that looks like ListView and supports inline edit? More specifically, a cell in the ListView should be editable when you double click on it, and the edit result should be automatically saved unless you hit ESC afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any WPF controls that do what you are looking for, but that is not indication that they don't exist. If you checkout the [WPF Toolkit on Codeplex](http://wpf.codeplex.com/), you may find something and there are a lot of OSS projects for WPF controls on [Codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=WPF&ac=8) in addition to the toolkit.

You can create one very easily taking advantage of the WPF content control model. Here is an example of a ListBox with a set of controls used to represent the objects bound to the list.

```
<ListBox x:Name="sampleListBox" 
         Width="500">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <GridRowDefinitions>
                   <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                   <RowDefinition Height="25"/> 
                </GridRowDefinitions>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Source="{Binding EditableProperty1}}"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Source="{Binding EditableProperty2}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

You can control the editability of the controls with Styles so that when the ListBox item is selected, the internal controls are editable but otherwise, they are not. I don't have access to my work laptop atm so I can't provide a style example but there are a lot of materials on the web that can help you. And if you have Expression Blend 4, it has a lot of functionality that can really help you when you are styling your own controls.

Comment: its better you go for the datagrid control